# How do I get users to access my website, but not without first going through another one?

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I have a website and now that I have several services on my site I have decided to create a kind of portal where users can choose which service they want.

The question is how do I ensure that users have to go through the portal since I have it on two separate domains?

For example
the website at `www.example.com`

and the portal in `www.web.com`

The idea is that whenever they enter `www.example.com` they have to first go to `www.web.com` and then have access to `www.example.com`

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+OR+htaccess+portal+before+website+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. "I haven't tried anything yet" is not a good start at SO

Comment: Maybe a shared authentication system (effectively SSO)? So if they haven't authenticated on the first one the token won't pass through to the second. Or...just don't do it on two separate domains. Seems to be more of a broad architecture question than a specific programming problem this, though. Might not be the best fit for Stackoverflow.

Comment: It's pretty broad, but at a conceptual level `www.web.com` could generate a token value and give that to the user.  When the user visits `www.example.com` they supply that token value to the server.  That server then makes a call to `www.web.com` in the background to validate the token.

Comment: Why do you want it set up this way?  That isn't the way the web is designed to work.  That prevents deep linking to the second site, not just the home page, but content pages as well.  Bookmarks won't work and search engines won't index it.